# confusing multi meter scale

Tags: current-measurement

In testing for a parasitic drain in my truck with this meter in ammeter mode, I realized the scale of the amp reading is ambiguous in that the reading does not change with the decimal point. This being the case, I am not sure if the output is in amps or milliamps. Can someone shed some light on what is happening?

[image: 2m 0.034]

[image: 20m 0.34]

[image: 200m 3.5]

[image: close up of dial]

Comment: The 10A range is shared with the 20mA range. Says so right by the switch. Readings on the other 2 ranges are meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual says that on the 10A range, the least-significant digit represents 0.01A, so those OP photos represent a reading of:

### **0.34A**

[image: sperry manual snippet]

 This is consistent with the maximum possible display (before overload) of "1999". On the 10A range, anything below 10.00A gives a valid reading. Any current reading 10.00A or above risks burning up the internal shunt.

It is interesting that they skipped the 2A range. A rather disappointing manual that is unclear.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEvKxc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The internals of a typical meter. The burden resistor values shown are for ease of calculation and assume that at full scale the burden voltage will be 200 mV. Table 1, above, shows that the actual burden voltage is 350 mV and different for the 10 A range so the OP's meter has some additional switching.*

How it works:

- On the 10 A range the 20 mA switch will be closed but since nothing is connected to the mA socket we can ignore it. At 10 A there will be a voltage drop of 100 mV across R4. The meter will read this (and it has a high input impedance so R1, R2 and R3 won't affect that) and will display 1000. The additional contacts of the range select will add the decimal point in the right location so that 10.00 A is read.
- Each of the other ranges selects a total burden set to give 200 mV at full scale current.
- Note again that the 10 A range is unfused. This could be lethal. Good quality meters are expensive for a reason.
- The 2000 mA range is missing. It would have required an extension of the switch logic and a 90 mΩ resistor between R1 and R4.

There is a full [DM-4100A schematic](https://file.ecmindustries.com/-/media/inriver/DM4100A_USE.pdf) on page 22 of the user manual but it's a poor quality scan.

Comment: The photos show the probes in the 10A and COM with the switch merrily being switched to various ranges. The meter module won't give an overload display until > 19.99 A (as it's just a 200 mV voltmeter and has no idea what is generating the voltage it is measuring) although the fuse may blow or the 10 A shunt may melt.

Comment: @Transistor yes overload > 19.99A, with a potentially overheated shunt. Corrected. It is odd that I missed seeing the "10A" of the "20m/10A" current range. A very strange arrangement. I wonder how long the 0.5A fuses survive in these instruments? And around car batteries, the 10A shunt is certainly at risk.

Answer (score 5):

If the red probe is in the "10A" hole, you must use the "10A" setting on the dial. The other dial settings are meaningless. The reading will be in amps when you use the proper setting (10A).